# Having trouble matching the 17 characters after the first comma

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to match 17 characters after the first comma.  The string ends at the second comma.  How do I match between these two commas using regex?  Is there a way to match the string if it varies in length?  Below is my test string.

0 PSC_OK,MACESBCE218002001,C07KTL89290003;1,C07KTL89290003,1;2,C07KTL89290003,0;3,C07KTL89290003,0;4,C07KTL89290003,0;5,C07KTL89290003,0;6,C07KTL89290003,0;7,C07KTL89290003,0;8,C07KTL89290003,0;9,C07KTL89290003,0;10,C07KTL89290003,0;11,C07KTL89290003,0;12,C07KTL89290003,0;13,C07KTL89290003,0;14,C07KTL89290003,0;15,C07KTL89290003,0;16,C07KTL89290003,0;17,C07KTL89290003,0;18,C07KTL89290003,0;19,C07KTL89290003,0;20,C07KTL89290003,0;21,C07KTL89290003,0;22,C07KTL89290003,0;23,C07KTL89290003,0;24,C07KTL89290003,0;25,C07KTL89290003,0;26,C07KTL89290003,0;27,C07KTL89290003,0;28,C07KTL89290003,0;29,C07KTL89290003,0;30,C07KTL89290003,0;31,C07KTL89290003,0;32,C07KTL89290003,0;33,C07KTL89290003,0;34,C07KTL89290003,0;35,C07KTL89290003,0;36,C07KTL89290003,0;37,C07KTL89290003,0;38,C07KTL89290003,0;39,C07KTL89290003,0;40,C07KTL89290003,0

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "matching 17 characters" - do you mean you want to check that it is "MACESBCE218002001", or do you mean that the string length between the 2 commas is 17 chars, or do you want to extract 17 chars after the comma to see what it is?

Comment: could you show what kind of regex you have tried so far?

Comment: ^,{0,17} is what I am stumbling on using regexr right now.  I can't see to only select that single string between the two commas.  I want the string between the commas it will be 17 characters but was interested if it could be done dynamically

Comment: (?<=,).{0,17}+(?=,)

Comment: This provides the right output

Comment: This provides this right output but I get a runtime error about nested quantifier.  Does anyone have an expression that would accomplish the same idea?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can build a regex expression like

```
/(,?)([a-zA-Z0-9;_]+)(,?)/gi
```

With Regex Expression you can get any match or group, the sitaxis change according to language, but, it almost the same.

And you can test it in page [Regexr](https://regexr.com/)

Comment: This does not provide the result expect

Comment: Yes it does, you need access to matches and then group 1... In Regex (...) this is a group... Matches is a list of all coincidences... You can try it in the link that added.

Comment: I need to parse the string and return only a single match, similar to 
(?<=,).{0,17}+(?=,) matches.  But I am running into runtime nested quantifier errors when using this expression in C#